# Display Multiple columns in Grid View Based on Check Box List

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Ola - I have an `asp:Gridview` that I always want to have 0 shown (the Locale) - now have the remaining hidden, unless it's corresponding check box is selected from the checkboxlist.

This is my sytnax - how would I achieve such in jquery or javascript?

```
    <div>    
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkboxlist1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="table" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="vertical"></asp:CheckBoxList>    
</div>

<div id="dgv">
        <asp:GridView ID="gridviewpeople" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Locale" HeaderText="Location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="James" HeaderText="James" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Joe" HeaderText="Joe" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Jack" HeaderText="Jack" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Frank" HeaderText="Frank" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Larry" HeaderText="Larry" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**EDIT**
I try the below JQuery - but the columns are not displayed when checkbox is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=chkCountry]").click(function () {
            var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
            var th = $("[id*=gridviewpeople] th:contains('James')");
            th.css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            $("[id*=gridviewpeople] tr").each(function () {
                $(this).find("td").eq(th.index()).css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            });
            var th1 = $("[id*=gridviewpeople] th1:contains('Joe')");
            th1.css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            $("[id*=gridviewpeople] tr").each(function () {
                $(this).find("td").eq(th1.index()).css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            });
            var th2 = $("[id*=gridviewpeople] th2:contains('Jack')");
            th2.css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            $("[id*=gridviewpeople] tr").each(function () {
                $(this).find("td").eq(th2.index()).css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            });
            var th3 = $("[id*=gridviewpeople] th3:contains('Jack')");
            th3.css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            $("[id*=gridviewpeople] tr").each(function () {
                $(this).find("td").eq(th3.index()).css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            });
            var th4 = $("[id*=gridviewpeople] th4:contains('Frank')");
            th4.css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            $("[id*=gridviewpeople] tr").each(function () {
                $(this).find("td").eq(th4.index()).css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            });
            var th5 = $("[id*=gridviewpeople] th5:contains('Larry')");
            th5.css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            $("[id*=gridviewpeople] tr").each(function () {
                $(this).find("td").eq(th5.index()).css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why the neg? - what is so bad about the question

Answer (score 0):

you can give it a try using JQuery based on your checkbox List

Comment: see my edit.  I just realized I forgot to include the JQuery I attempted.

Comment: Can You send me your application to help you because really I can't read it like this i need to debug the JQuery and see what is going on

Comment: and please use classes rather than using the ID's much better

Comment: I can not send application as it is tied to mssql server database tables :(

Comment: classes rather than id's?

Comment: when you use the CssClasses at any control you have in you app you can access it in JQuery much better because the ID's at run time will be modified or you can use the Client id if you want to

Comment: for example you can use it like this :
$('#' + '<%= chkCountry.ClientID %>').click(function() {
});

Comment: Thank you for those tips - I Had no idea you could do such

Comment: you are welcome dude and I hope that your problem would be solved using this tips ;)